# No such element issue occurring on mobile test automation using Appium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, appium

I am using Appium and selenium to automate this registration page https://www.gridlastic.com/register.php

```
public class GridlasticRegistrationPage extends BasePage {

@FindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='First Name']") WebElement FIRST_NAME_TEXT_BOX;
@FindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[@text='Last Name']") WebElement LAST_NAME_TEXT_BOX;


public void navigateToGridlasticRegistrationPage(){
    driver.get("https://www.gridlastic.com/register.php");
}


public void register(String fName, String lName){
    waitForElement(FIRST_NAME_TEXT_BOX);
    FIRST_NAME_TEXT_BOX.sendKeys(fName);
    waitForElement(LAST_NAME_TEXT_BOX);
    LAST_NAME_TEXT_BOX.sendKeys(lName);
   GET_FREE_ACCOUNT_BUTTON.click();
  }

}
```

But in this code, I am getting following error.

```
    Failed Step: Register to Gridlastic using First Name, Last Name, Comapany, Work Email, Username and Password in the following table <table:/resources/gridlastic_registration_details.csv>
    Specification: specs\GridlasticRegistration.spec:16
    Error Message: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: Proxy element for: org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator@fae9e82
    Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '61506a4624b13675f24581e453592342b7485d71', time: '2015-06-04 10:22:50'
    System info: host: 'Mitrai-OsandaN', ip: '192.168.88.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
    Capabilities [{deviceScreenSize=768x1280, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false, version=5.1.0, deviceName=192.168.88.101:5555, platform=ANDROID, deviceUDID=192.168.88.101:5555, desired={browserName=chrome, platformName=Android, version=5.1.0, deviceName=My phone, platform=ANDROID}, platformVersion=5.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceModel=Custom Phone - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 768x1280, platformName=Android, deviceManufacturer=unknown}]
    Session ID: 4ec65f50-9746-4093-ae33-f0d1f735652f
    Stacktrace: 
    org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:229)
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Even if I remove the "WebDriverWait wait", it says "No such element". I think issue is in the xpath. But I have tried with many xpaths, still get the same error.

Please note that I am using android chrome browser to automate this scenario.

Comment: Try to replace predicate `[@text='First Name']` with `[@placeholder='First Name']`

Comment: yes. It has to be placeholder.

Comment: @ Andersson I tried by using placeholder. But it didn't work. Same error occurs. Please note that I am using android chrome browser to automate this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the answer for this issue. I used android chrome browser widget's xpath for the element. It is wrong and the fix is that I have to use desktop browser's xpath as the following.

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='fname']") WebElement FIRST_NAME_TEXT_BOX;
```

Comment: Nice going, Osanda.  Please mark your own answer as the accepted answer so that this question does not appear as no accepted answer.